# FortiClient on OS X generates cascading error 113

Tags: macos-catalina, forticlient

On occasion, I get an error that reads `The VPN connection terminates unexpectedly (Error Code: -113)`, which cascades across the screen:

[image]

Any suggestions to eliminate the error would be helpful.